# android - How to update a specific textview of a CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

My first cardView shows an alert dialog, i want that the item selected on the dialog set into the description of my first cardView.

How can i reference to a specific cardView?

i have this

```
holder.mTextDescription.setText(string);
```

it sets the text, but it does on the last cardView.

i actually solve it, but not sure if this is the bes way to do it;

```
private void onUpdate(int position, String string) {
    String titulo = mDataset.get(position).titulo;
    String type = mDataset.get(position).type;
    mDataset.remove(position);
    mDataset.add(position, new Archivos(titulo, string, type));
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: I guess you are using a recyclerview adapter? can you paste your class?

Comment: i actually solve it, but not sure if this is the bes way to do it;

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case having a method that receives the updated string and the position at which your object is, works. It could be somehow improved like this

```
Archivos archivos = mDataSet.get(position); 
archivos.setXXXXX(stringVariable)
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Gets the object once, update your property and notify that something changed at that position.